# What is the latest version of Safari that runs on PowerPC (PPC)?

Tags: safari, software-update, powerpc

I wonder if Apple still delivers new version of safari for PowerPC-based macs. On that computer, I'm stuck with firefox 3.6.28. Is Safari still updated on PPC system updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [depends on the OS](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#safari) you're running.

- Leopard: [Safari 5.0.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1422)
- Tiger: [Safari 4.1.3](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1069)

Newer Macs can use...

- Snow Leopard/Lion: [Safari 5.1.4](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1070)

Comment: Can I be confident about the fact that Software-Updates will install the lastest possible version on that computer and stops before the first incompatible one? (Not as Firefox that keeps asking me to update to v11!)

Comment: @Rabskatran I'm 99% convinced that Apple's Software update will not install incompatible Software by Apple. Therefore, you should not be prompted. Apple's software update has not prompted you to update to Safari 5 on your current os, has it?

Answer (score 2):

Safari for leopard has been discontinued. If you are looking for a browser that is currently receiving updates [TenFourFox](http://www.floodgap.com/software/tenfourfox/) is a fork of firefox that is updated along side the primary version, but remains compatible with PowerPC cpu's.

Answer (score 1):

While Safari 5.0.6 is the last version for 10.5, newer versions of the webkit framework can be obtained from the leopard-webkit project https://code.google.com/p/leopard-webkit/ . Webkit based applications can use the newer framework to provide updated rendering.